# how to convert joda datetime to String and vice versa

Tags: java, datetime

Is there a way to convert Joda DateTime to String and then from that String to DateTime.

```
DateTime d = ..;
String date = d.toString();
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date);
```

My question is that whether the above approach is valid or need to use formatter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dtStr = fmt.print(dt);
```

Comment: Trap: This code omits the time zone from the format, so the value you get back is not necessarily the value you started with.

Comment: question asked for two conversion (datetime -> string -> datetime) but this just provides one way (datetime -> string).

Answer (score 6):

For those who want to parse back the value from **`toString`** can read my answer.

If you to read the implementation of `DateTime` closely. The `toString` method is override by `AbstractInstant`.

```
@ToString
public String toString() {
    return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(this);
}
```

Now, parse the value from `toString`:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String dtStr = dt.toString();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime newDt = fmt.parse(dtStr);
```